# How to remove time count from intervalToDuration in date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

How to remove time countdown from `intervalToDuration` in date-fns?

```
 let duration = intervalToDuration({
    start: new Date('2022-03-24'),
    end: new Date(),
  });

  const newD = formatDuration(duration, {
    delimiter: ', ',
  });
  console.log(newD);
```

From the above function result is **6 months, 5 days, 4 hours, 8 minutes, x seconds**

What I'm expecting is **6 months, 5 days**

Comment: `end: new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to adjust the dates used to calculate the duration.

In case you want to change the formatted output, not the `duration` itself:

`formatDuration` accepts a `format` in its options: https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/formatDuration

E.g.

```js
formatDuration(
  {
    months: 9,
    days: 7,
    hours: 5,
    minutes: 9,
    seconds: 30
  },
  { format: ['months', 'days'] }
)
```

Comment: I was about to send the same answer +1

Comment: Why aren't weeks there?

Comment: You can add weeks. Depends on your requirements...